# What happens to registers when there are more than 32 variables?

Tags: assembly, programming-languages, mips

> One major difference between the variables of a programming language and registers is the limited number of registers, typically 32 on current computers, like MIPS.

This is what I read while studying MIPS language. Assume that there is a program which has more than 32 variables and each variable stored in a register. What will happen the rest of variables while there is no empty register?

Comment: Assume that all variables are **not** stored in registers in that case. So at least some are stored in memory.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "MIPS language".  Any compiler that generates code to run on a MIPS processor deals with this by storing excess variables in the stack frame.

Comment: I suspect that @nrz meant "not all variables are" rather than "all variables are not". The point is that, at any given time, you can only hold a limited number of variables in registers, and the rest will reside in memory until they are needed (there's no instruction that takes 33 operands as far as I know).

Comment: @Michael Correct, that's exactly what I meant. English is not my native language...

Comment: The art of assembly language programming, whether it be MIPS or any architecture, is about managing your variables as to which are in registers and which are in memory at any given time. The limit in number of registers just affects that balance of where they variable is kept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all MIPS 32 registers are used to store variables, some has special uses like `$k0`, `$k1`, `$gp`, `$sp`, so the available registers for storing variables are less.

Usually variables are not stored in registers, they are stored in memory by creating a stack frame for the function like here:

```
# make space of 30 vars, 4 bytes each
addi    $sp, $sp, -4 * 30

# $t0 = 1
addi    $t0, $0, 1

# store vars into the stack
sw      $t0, 0($sp)  # 1
addi    $t0, $t0, 1  # $t0++
sw      $t0, 4($sp)  # 2
addi    $t0, $t0, 1  # $t0++
sw      $t0, 8($sp)  # 3
addi    $t0, $t0, 1  # $t0++
sw      $t0, 12($sp) # 4
#...

# now to access the 4th var, 12($sp), into $t1
lw      $t1, 12($sp)

# do stuff

# deallocate the space and destroy those vars when you done
addi    $sp, $sp, 4 * 30
```

when you want to update the variable or use it heavily like in counters, you load it from the memory into a register, do what you want to do and then update the memory stored variable.

Comment: Thank you for answers. This is the answer I found on the same book in further chapters. "Many programs have more variables than computers have registers. Consequently,
the compiler tries to keep the most frequently used variables in registers and
places the rest in memory, using loads and stores to move variables between registers and memory. The process of putting less commonly used variables (or those
needed later) into memory is called spilling registers."